# Android background TCP connection

Tags: android, service, tcp

I developed a VOIP app on Android which is working pretty good since we changed from GCM to our own push service by having a sticky background service running with a TCP connection. I made my own solution instead of GCM because realtime pushes are not really working.

Like I said normally everything works pretty nice and my service works most of the time but there is one big problem I can't seem to solve: When somebody uses games or apps with a lot of RAM usage my service gets killed and killed over again(it gets restarted through a alarm which detects it is not running anymore).

So how am I supposed to have the service running with a ongoing connection when the system kills me all the time? The only thing I can think about is to have a very fast Alarm like checking all 15s if my service is still running which seems like a bad idea.

Comment: services will be get killed. You have to use reciever(BroadCastReciever) to wake up the service.

Comment: The problem is not the wake up but that I have no chance to even run because I nearly instantly get killed after the wake up because the system needs ram again

Comment: then you should make a custom Toast that prompt user a message to accept or reject chat when broadcastReciever recieves. when user press accept take them to your app.. and dont depend on service to handle

Comment: you need to use startForeground() method in service. Any change you are using alot of ram in your app?

Comment: The RAM usage is not coming from our app. I already read about Foreground Services but the problem should be the same, right ? If the system wants RAM it will kill me, even when the App requesting the RAM is leaking which should not be my problem.